# Word for the cost of duplication?

Tags: vocabulary

I know there is a word or two-word phrase (i.e. xxx-cost) that can be used in a business context to describe the cost of duplicating an item, but I can't remember it.

For example; for software this cost is near zero, whereas for diamond rings it is high.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Well, one might use "replication cost".

Comment: What do you mean by the *cost of duplicating an item*? Are you referring to *manufacturing cost* or the cost of having someone else produce a copy, given an existing item?

Comment: [Overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_%28business%29)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**marginal cost**

> the cost added by producing one extra item of a product.

from google: marginal cost.

Answer (score 1):

You could use: **reproduction cost**

> The costs involved with identically reproducing an asset or property
>   with the same materials and specifications as an insured property
>   based on current prices. Insurers use reproduction cost as a method of
>   valuation to calculate the costs involved with the risk of replacing
>   an insured asset with an identical one at the same location.

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/reproduction-cost.asp